# Adding Parameter to href tag before uri

Tags: jsp-tags

I have Jsp with JSTL Tags.I want to add disp=true parameter in href before adding uri
I have added  `href="<r:url?&disp=true uri="utb:open" mode="view" lateBinding="true" />"` like this but it's givinng and Error.Anyone can please tell me how to add that parameter .

Here is the Code:

```
<a id="utb-edit-mode-quicklink" href="<r:url uri="utb:open" mode="view" lateBinding="true" />" title="${editModeDesc}"><portal-fmt:text key="toolbar.editPage" bundle="com.ibm.wps.toolbar.resources.Toolbar"/></a>
```

Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this(not shure what the r:url tag does though)

`href="<r:url uri="utb:open" mode="view" lateBinding="true" />&disp=true"`

P.S. posting the error could help.